# BL2.80 - Remapping the Context, Search, Tool-Shelf popups

Tags: customization

new user here.

As the title mentions, I am doing some customizations and I am trying to find where in the keymap settings these menu popups are buried (Context popup, Search box, and the main tool-shelf).

The tool-shelf, for example, can be assigned in 2.8 to the spacebar action, but I don't see it inside the keymap tree structure anywhere.

Comment: You mentioned "these" in your question but there's nothing to see for "these".

Comment: The ones from the title